# Where put workers.properties for mod_jk.so Tomcat connector to Apache httpd (OS X)?

Tags: apache, tomcat7, mod-jk

I'm trying to set up the Tomcat 7 connector mod_jk.so on OS X (10.8.3) so that calls to Tomcat will go through httpd from apache 2.2. The file mod_jk.so is in place. But where does workers.properties go? The instructions at http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/webserver_howto/apache.html just don't seem to say.

Comment: Did you see the answer below? Was it helpful?

Comment: @Michael: I'm just getting back to tomcat after being diverted on some other work. I also have to figure out whether the minimal JkWorkersFile suffices or whether something longer, as in the default, is needed. This is strictly for a localhost environment.

Comment: You can accepts and promote my answer if it answers your question :)

Comment: I finally just gave up on how to do all the configuration needed for `mod_jk.so` and instead have been able to route Tomcat through Apache httpd by using instead `mod_proxy_ajp.so`. I hope the constrained packet size of the latter, compared to the former, will suffice: my main use of Tomcat is for *webMathematica*, where a lot of data for graphics (generated on the fly by the underlying *Mathematica* engine) may be involved.

Comment: WELL DONE! Sorry was not able to help you.

Comment: @Michael: And even using `mod_proxy_ajp` wasn't exactly obvious for configuration: I had to modify `httpd.conf` (of course) as well as `httd-vhosts.conf` and `/etc/hosts`. (This is for OS X.)

Answer (score 1):

I know you're now using `mod_proxy` but I'm answering this for the record, at least to include the info when your *nix packaging framework is involved.

In Debian, the package `apache2` installs apache with the configuration directory `/etc/apache2/mods-available` and the seperate package `libapache2-mod-jk` places an apache config file in this directory called `jk.conf`, which gets pulled in by apache at start-up.

`jk.conf` has the `JkWorkersFile` directive.

The `libapache2-mod-jk` package also installs a `workers.properties` file under `/etc/libapache2-mod-jk`.

So for `OS X`, you put your workers.properties file anywhere, e.g. rationally in the same dir as the `httpd.conf`, and then you have to put the directive either in your `httpd.conf` file, or that might contain an `Include` to pull in everything in a directory, e.g. `conf.d` where you can put custom stuff in your own files that won't get interfered with at package upgrades.

Answer (score 0):

Please put your workers.properties file according to your JkWorkersFile configuration:

```
JkWorkersFile     /etc/httpd/conf/workers.properties
```

Comment: Is that correct? I ask because I have no directory `/etc/httpd/conf`. Rather, my `httpd.conf` is in `/opt/local/apache2/conf`. My apache2 installation is the macports version, so the whole apache2 tree is put inside `/opt/local`.

Comment: You put it according to JkWorkersFile property.
You can set it to any directory you have permissions

Comment: Sorry, I'm now totally lost. Where does one set JkWorkersFile? According to http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/webserver_howto/apache.html, it seems if one uses Tomcat auto-configure (by adding `Include $TOMCAT_HOME/conf/jk/mod_jk.conf-auto` at the end of `httpd.conf`, then the setting for `JWorkersFile` ought to be generated automatically. But how do Tomcat (or apache?) know where that is?

Comment: Things are even worse than I thought: My `$TOMCAT_ROOT` is `/user/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.37`, and in the subdirectory `conf` of that, there's no such file as `mod_jk.conf-auto`.

Comment: Does the setting for `JWorkersFile` to into `httpd.conf` or, if not, where?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. But later I found that I should first look whether I am using mod_jk.so or mod_proxy_ajp in httpd.conf. I turned out to be tha later one. So instead of editing the worker.properties, which I don't have, I should edit the httpd.conf: Add a ProxyIOBufferSize directive to Apache httpd's configuration.

```
ProxyIOBufferSize 65536
```

Hope it helps.

Ref: [Here](https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/SHIB2/NativeSPJavaInstall) at the bottom of the page.